# Passport JwtStrategy never executed in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I am using nestjs and having an issue with using guards to authenticate a request.
My JwtStrategy is never execute.

Here is my JwtStrategy :

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt') {
  constructor(
    @Inject('IQueryBusAdapter')
    private readonly queryBus: IQueryBusAdapter,
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
    });
  }

  validate = async (payload: IJwtPayload) => {
    Logger.log('INNNNN');

    const query = new GetUserByIdQuery();
    query.id = payload.id;

    const user = await this.queryBus.execute(query);
    if (!(user instanceof User)) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    return user;
  };
}
```

I also try to call directly `validate()` directly in constructor but nothing change...

My AuthModule :

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    BusModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secretOrPrivateKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES,
      },
    }),
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
  ],
  controllers: [RegisterAction, LoginAction],
  providers: [
    JwtStrategy,
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

My controller

```js
@Get('/:id')
  @ApiOperation({ title: 'Get user ressource' })
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  async index(@Param() query: GetUserByIdQuery): Promise<object> {
    const user = await this.queryBus.execute(query);

    if (!(user instanceof User)) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }

    return {
      id: user.id,
      fullName: user.getFullName(),
      email: user.email
    };
  }
```

I always received 401 status code.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `validate` will only be called when you pass a valid jwt token. When the token is signed with a different secret or is expired, `validate` will never be called. Can you make sure that you have a valid `Authorization` header?

Comment: My token was always expired ! Thanks for your help Kim.

Comment: Consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`validate` will only be called when you pass a valid jwt token. When the token is signed with a different secret or is expired, `validate` will never be called. Make sure you have a valid token. You can check your token with the [jwt debugger](https://jwt.io/).